# Avoid repeating selection when I have empty cells in range

Tags: vba, excel

I am a bit of a VBA novice so was hoping someone could help with the following. 
I need to select (and clear the contents of) all cells in a workbook before pasting new data in. Problem is when I use the (xlToLeft) command it stops when it encounters an empty cell.

I have the code below (which works) but wanted to see if there is a better way, which I am sure there will be.

```
    Sheets("TEST").Activate
    Range("BB3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select

    Selection.ClearContents
```

Just for reference I have info in the cells to the right which I want to keep and the rows will change on each occasion I run the script.

Answer (score 1):

Why not clear all cells instead of looking for the ones with something in them?

```
Sheets("TEST").Activate
Activesheet.cells.ClearContents
```

Comment: Activating here is unnecessary (and should be avoided when possible) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1

Comment: Hey Jeremy, I have some data in cells A1:BF2 and BB3:BF3 that i need to keep. Some headers and formulas so unfortunately can't clear all.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to clear a set range:

```
Worksheets("Test1").Range("A1:I60").ClearContents
```

If you wish to clear a range based on a value in a row (* is a wildcard, you can substitute it for a text string if required):

```
Dim lRow as Integer
lRow = Worksheets("Test1").Range("I:I").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Worksheets("Test1").Range("A1:I" & lRow).ClearContents
```

Best practice is to avoid using .Select/.Activate and any other indirect reference to a workbook/worksheet/range/cell and provide a fixed reference. Using any non-fixed reference slows down code execution but also makes it hard to review the code at a future date.

Answer (score 0):

first things first - you should avoid using `Select` altogether.

> It's a rather bad coding habit in VBA that's going to do you more harm
>   than good in the long run. I'm not going to go into too much detail
>   here, but I'd recommend reading *(thoroughly)* this question here:
>   [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1)

---

I've created the following procedure:

### `clear_til_empty(ByVal inrow as Long)`

> Finds last non-empty cell in a specified row (`inrow`) and removes the cells in their respective columns.

```
Private Sub clear_til_empty(ByVal inrow As Long)
' clears all the cell contents until it hits an empty cell
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
  Dim lc As Long ' last empty column
  lc = ws.Cells(inrow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  ' ws.Range("1:" & lc).ClearContents // didn't work as expected

  For i = 1 To lc
    ws.Columns(i).ClearContents
  Next i

End Sub
```

---

So for example, if we wanted to remove data from all columns, until an empty cell is hit in the first row, we would use the following invokation.

```
clear_til_empty(1)
```

Obviously, you can pass a variable to it instead.

Comment: No problem, but more importantly,what about the actual answer. Does it work as intended?\

Comment: Thanks for the tip re .Select and the input on how best to solve my problem I went with the solution below because it was more simple for a novice like myself.